# Difference between bean method with AjaxBehaviorEvent and bean method without AjaxBehaviorEvent?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, dom-events

I have my XHTML like this

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="Keyup: " />
        <p:inputText id="counter">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out"
                listener="#{counterBean.increment}" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{counterBean.count}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**Case I : ajax listener method with `AjaxBehaviorEvent`**

```
public void increment(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        count++;
    }
```

**Case II : without `AjaxBehaviorEvent`**

```
 public void increment() {
       count++;
}
```

In both the cases listener will be invoked and does the counter job to increase count on `keyup`. So, When exactly I need to use `AjaxBehaviorEvent` and when I don't need to use?

Comment: `AjaxBehaviorEvent` will give you access to the component that fired the event. From which you can get a lot of information. This is the major advantage. Also, you can fire and process a custom `FacesEvent` and also broadcast an additional `BehaviorEvent` that other listeners can process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind multiple ajax events to the same method and use `getSource()` of `AjaxBehaviorEvent`  to know which component trigged the event.

Comment: Yeah.That make sense.Are there any other uses?